# Cordova app Uncaught SyntaxError after Android 5.1 device reset

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I did a device reset on a device running Android 5.1, but afterwards my apps built with Cordova could not open when installing them again. Just a blank white screen is shown now. When inspecting the app I find the issue Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode.

So I'm guessing the device reset removed the latest support for the JS keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the WebView was outdated, just had to update the Android System WebView:

[image: Android System WebView]

Comment: I was having the same issue on old devices only (Android 6.0.1). This fixes it, but now I´m worried about the user experience.. If the app crashes (white screen, js errors, etc) because of this, could it be any way to detect it to show a warning suggesting the user to download the "Android System WebView"?